# Raspberry Pi Has No Hostname

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi

The IP of my R Pi is 192.168.1.110. On my computer, `arp -a` shows `192.168.1.110`. I can ping this IP or SSH into the Pi with the IP and it works correctly. However, if I execute the command `ping raspberrypi` shell says that name is not resolved. I cannot use the Pi's hostname to connect for some reason.

How do I fix this? (Note: I tried adding my local DNS server IP to `/etc/resolv.conf` but nothing changed... help??

Comment: Have you tried flushing the DNS of your client that you're trying to ping from?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your PI by hostname you will need to setup your router to provide a static IP to your PI by MAC address.

On your router make sure you have a range of IP's set aside for static addresses. I use 192.168.1.2-99. You will begin by assigning the PI a static IP using its MAC address in the DHCP Table on the router.

Router example:

```
 DHCP Table
 XBOX:192.168.1.10
 RAPI:192.168.1.20
```

Give your PI a static IP.

On your PI use: sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

- look for the line: iface eth0 inet dhcp
- change the line to: iface eth0 inet static

Add the following changes:

```
                   address 192.168.x.x
                   netmask 255.255.255.0
                   gateway 192.168.x.1

 Exit nano, make sure you saved the file.
  Reboot the PI using sudu reboot.
```

Once the PI is back up you can type in ifconfig to make sure the changes took.

Get your PI's MAC address: ifconfig
The PI's MAC address is the letters and numbers following HWaddr.

Now in your Router, you will need to find where you can assign Permanent Address Reservations in your DHCP server. It differs from brand to brand but should be identifiable. You will enter in your PI's mac address and the static IP you gave it using nano. Save and reboot your router.

Now that you have assigned the PI a static DHCP reservation in your router you will need to log back into your PI and REMOVE the changes made earlier.

```
     - look for the line: iface eth0 inet static
     - change the line to: iface eth0 inet dhcp
           delete  address 192.168.x.x
           delete  netmask 255.255.255.0
           delete  gateway 192.168.x.1
     Exit nano, make sure you saved the file.
     Reboot the PI using sudu reboot.
```

You should now be able to ping your PI by hostname. 
PING RAPI

Comment: Have you had any success? Or are you still having issues?